# Dynamically adding input elements to form in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dom

I am trying to dynamically add state to an array from my form in such a way that multiple inputs can eventually be saved as state in the same array, much like the redux form but I don't know Redux yet.

I don't know how to access the current array I am in so I can set the current input value as state.  In this case, I am trying to save the name of the ingredient inside the ingredient array within the recipe state by mapping over the current array.  Problem is when I try to map over the current array it apparently isn't an array at all and I get the following error when I try to enter data into the input..

```
TypeError: currentIngredients.map is not a function
(anonymous function)
src/components/recipes/Recipe_Form.js:68
  65 | <input
  66 |   onChange={e => {
  67 |     const name = e.target.value;
> 68 |     setRecipe((currentIngredients) =>
     | ^  69 |       currentIngredients.map(x =>
  70 |         x.id === i.id
  71 |           ? {
```

. I am unsure how to access the ingredient array in such a way that I can edit state.

thanks

```
export const Recipe_Form = () => {
  const recipeContext = useContext(RecipeContext);

  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState({
    title: "",
    img: "",
    ingredients: [{ id: "1", name: "cheese", amount: "200" }],
    method: "",
    serves: "",
    time: "",
  });

  const onChange = (e) =>
    setRecipe({ ...recipe, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    recipeContext.addRecipe(recipe);
    setRecipe({
      title: "",
      img: "",
      ingredients: [],
      method: "",
      serves: "",
      time: "",
    });
  };

  const { title, img, ingredients, method, serves, time } = recipe;

  return (
    <div className='row center-align'>
      <form className='col s12' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        {/* Image */}
        <div className='input-field col s12 center-align'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Please enter an image url'
            name='img'
            value={img}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
        {/* Title */}
        <div className='input-field col s12 center-align'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Please enter recipe title'
            className='validate'
            name='title'
            value={title}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>

        {ingredients.map((i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i.id}>
              <input
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const name = e.target.value;
                  setRecipe((currentIngredients) =>
                    currentIngredients.map((x) =>
                      x.id === i.id
                        ? {
                            ...x,
                            name,
                          }
                        : x
                    )
                  );
                  // e.target.value
                }}
                value={i.name}
                placeholder='ingredient'
              />

              <input value={i.amount} placeholder='amount' />
            </div>
          );
        })}
        {/* Method */}
        <div className='methodContainer'>
          <div className='row method-line'>
            <div className='input-field col s12 center-align'>
              <input
                type='text'
                placeholder='Please enter method'
                className='validate'
                name='method'
                value={method}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a className='btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red'>
          <i className='fas fa-plus'></i>
        </a>
        {/* Serves */}
        <div className='input-field col s12 center-align'>
          <input
            type='number'
            placeholder='Number of servings'
            className='validate'
            name='serves'
            value={serves}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
        {/* Time */}
        <div className='input-field col s12 center-align'>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Time to compelete...'
            className='validate'
            name='time'
            value={time}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <button
          className='btn waves-effect waves-light'
          type='submit'
          name='action'>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Recipe_Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this, because the `currentIngredients` is actually your state object? you don't have to use it that way. You can do something like that:

```
setRecipe({
  ...recipe,
  ingredients: recipe.ingredients.map(x =>
    x.id === i.id
      ? {
          ...x,
          name
        }
      : x
  )
});
```